# API-Monitor not logging buffer

Tags: memory, networking, api-reversing

I have a problem with API-Monitor.

When I try to capture data (here: network traffic), API-Monitor doesn't log the buffer from the recieved data. For send() it works well, but for recv() it doesn't show the buffer. I really don't know why this is happening. Both buffers reside in a valid memory space before and after the call.

I think its either because API-Monitor doesn't recogonize the size of the buffer and therefore doesn't capture the content or it only monitors const char* types of buffers (idk why but thats the difference between the singature of the two functions).

Here are some images:

[image]

it works with send(). It logs all the data that was sent

[image]

and here it says "Not Avaliable". Nothing shows up in the buffer-viewer. The return-value ist 5 so we can be sure that actually data was written into the buffer.

Comment: Well I fixed it by changing the definition of the function. Now I changed the length of the buffer to Length (length of the buffer passed) instead of PostLength (length of the return value). Somehow API-Monitor has a problem when logging a buffer after the call.